# Moving MySQL rows using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database.

Members are loaded that are active.

The tables are somewhat like this:

```
Table Name: recipients

Columns:    recipient_id
            member_id
```

Then I have a table named `recipients_banned`
The columns are the same as in `recipients`.

What I want to do is have a yes/no field in a form (PHP) that, when clicked, moves all the people with `member_id` in `recipients` table to `recipients_banned` table.

Any assistance with some initial code for this would be appreciated. Is this at all possible without deleting all of the data? Please note that the rows in `recipients` should be deleted once moved.

Comment: Ok. What is the question, **what have you tried?** If you'd just like to order software, you are at the wrong address here.

Comment: What I am trying to find out is would a yes/no be able to do this without losing the data basically just moving it between two tables and deleting it from the first table

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have an eg "member_is_active" column, with a true/false value stored there, rather than an entirely separate table?

Comment: you do you mean click in PHP?

Comment: @d'alar'cop My mistake in editing.  Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean to use this from a browser? So PHP will create a button that you can click?..

Answer (score 1):

```
recipients                     recipients_banned

recipient_id | member_id       recipient_id | member_id
------------------------       ------------------------
11           | 21              31           | 32
21           | 22              41           | 42
```

Actually, you didn't explain your question in detail. So, I have tried to guess something about your question and give you some tips. For example, we have a PHP file with a name of *form.php*:

```
<form action="form.php?q=yes" method="get">
  Recipient ID: <input type="text" name="recipient_id">
  Member ID: <input type="text" name="member_id">
  <input type="submit" value="Move">
</form>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$password", "$database");

$r = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["recipient_id"];
$m = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["member_id"];
$q = $_GET["q"];

if ($q = yes) {
    $i = "INSERT INTO `recipients_banned` ( `recipient_id` , `member_id` )
    VALUES (
      '$r' , '$m'
    );";

    $d = "DELETE FROM `recipients` WHERE `recipient_id` = $r AND `member_id` = '$m' LIMIT 1;";

    mysqli_query($con, "$i
    $d");
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If we try to input *"21"* in **Recipient ID** field and *"22"* in **Member ID** field and then click the **Move** button, the database tables' contents would look like this:

```
recipients                     recipients_banned

recipient_id | member_id       recipient_id | member_id
------------------------       ------------------------
11           | 21              21           | 22
                               31           | 32
                               41           | 42
```

Feel free to revise this answer if something isn't right!

Comment: I have revised the code as above. It is not doing much on the SQL

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't clear.. For example, the data of our tables are:

```
recipients               | recipients_banned
recipient_id | member_id | recipient_id | member_id
------------------------ | ------------------------
1            | 21        |
2            | 22        |
```

If you just want to have *"Yes"* and *"No"* radio buttons on a form that when you've selected the *"Yes"* button and then submitted, all the data in **recipients** table will be moved into the **recipients_banned** table, then you should better try this code. For example we've a PHP file named as *form.php*:

```
<form action="form.php" method="get">
  <input type="radio" name="q" value="1">Yes<br />
  <input type="radio" name="q" value="0">No
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$user", "$password", "$database");
$q = $_GET["q"];

if ($q == 1) {
    $i = "INSERT INTO `recipients_banned` ( `recipient_id` , `member_id` )
    SELECT recipient_id , member_id
    FROM `recipients`;";
    $d = "DELETE FROM `recipients`;";

    mysqli_query($con, "$i
    $d");

    echo '"recipients" data is moved to "recipients_banned"!';
} else if ($q == 0) {
    echo "Nothing is moved!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If you select *"No"* and then submit it, the output will be *"Nothing is moved!"*. But if you select *"Yes"* before submitting it, the database tables result which is unseen will become as the tables below with an output of *'"recipients" data is moved to "recipients_banned"!'*:

```
recipients               | recipients_banned
recipient_id | member_id | recipient_id | member_id
------------------------ | ------------------------
                         | 1            | 21
                         | 2            | 22
```